# Allow client to client communication in OpenVPN for certain IP range

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, iptables

**The Goal**

We've got one OpenVPN Server that's up and running (10.8.0.0/16). And some clients. Clients can be separated into two specific groups: humans and non-humans. The non-humans shall only have access to the VPN server and a couple of external IP addresses through the VPN. The humans on the other hand shall have access to everything - especially to the non-humans (non-human clients have a web interface the humans shall reach).

**What works**

Humans and non-humans can connect to the VPN. Non-human access is successfully restricted.

**The Problem**

When connected with a human client, I cannot ping the non-human client nor can I reach the web interface of the non-human client.

```
~ ping 10.8.0.2
PING 10.8.0.2 (10.8.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 2.0.8.10)
From 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 2.0.8.10)
From 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=4 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 2.0.8.10)
```

**Configs**

server.conf

```
local 192.168.12.152
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
management 127.0.0.1 5555
```

sample_client.ovpn (The Difference between humans and non-humans is made by ccd where clients get a static IP-address. Humans get a IP address from 10.8.255.0/24 and non-humans from 10.8.x.y [x != 255] - so in the ccd there is just 'ifconfig-push 10.8.y.y 255.255.0.0').

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote some-vpn-dyndns.net 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
verb 3
<ca>[...]</ca>
<cert>[...]</cert>
<key>[...]</key>
<tls-crypt>[...]</tls-crypt>
```

Iptable changes:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/16 ! -d 10.8.0.0/16 -j SNAT --to 192.168.12.152
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/16 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/16 -d 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT    <---for DNS
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/16 -d 8.8.8.8 -j ACCEPT    <---for DNS
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/16 -d 213.187.93.146 -j ACCEPT   <--- special (dummy) server that non-humans have to reach
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.255.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

This adds to this iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1194

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.255.0/24        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/16          213.187.93.146       
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/16          8.8.8.8             
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/16          1.1.1.1             
DROP       all  --  10.8.0.0/16          0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

tl;dr If somebody could tell me why I'm not able to ping from a human client (10.8.255.1) a non-human client (10.8.0.2) - that would be really nice. (Everything else is working as it should)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution that kinda works.

What did I do?
I changed some FORWARD rules.

```
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.255.0/24        anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/16          some-dummy-server 
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/16          dns.google          
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/16          one.one.one.one     
ACCEPT     all  --  one.one.one.one      10.8.0.0/16         
ACCEPT     all  --  dns.google           10.8.0.0/16         
ACCEPT     all  --  some-dummy-server    10.8.0.0/16         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.8.255.0/24
```

First: the default policy for FORWARD is set to DROP. Second: allowed communication to default DNS-Servers for all of my VPN-Range, allowed communication to my special dummy server. Third: I allowed communication with everything and from everything with the IP range of my human clients.

Why do I say it kinda works? Because if I ping from a human client a non human client I still get this:

```
~ ping 10.8.0.2
PING 10.8.0.2 (10.8.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=120 ms
From 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 2.0.8.10)
64 bytes from 10.8.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=132 ms
From 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 2.0.8.10)
64 bytes from 10.8.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=108 ms
From 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=4 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 2.0.8.10)
64 bytes from 10.8.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=102 ms
```

I would guess that is because of the routing table on my (human) client side:

```
~ sudo route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     50     0        0 tun0
ip5b426419.dyna _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp0s20f3
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
_gateway        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
```

So if someone got a better idea, I'm happy to mark their answer as correct.

Ty for reading.